# Impact of change of domain controllers on Windows server hosting Tridion 2011 SP1

Tags: 2011, 2011-sp1

We are using windows authentication in Tridion 2011 SP1. There is no ldap configured.

[image]

My current domain name is example.local.

If there is a change in domain name, May I know the impacts and changes need to be done to comply with new domain.

Any help on this regard would be grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you adding a NEW domain controller to your machine or changing from DC to another?

Comment: @Shiva We are changing existing DC to another